# Thymeleaf and sql.Date

Tags: date, spring-mvc, time, thymeleaf

I have sql.Date and sql.Time fields in my entity and want to edit their values using text inputs.
Declaration in the entity

```
@DateTimeFormat (pattern="HH:mm")
private Time time;

@DateTimeFormat (pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date date;
```

Template

```
<input id="date" name="date" type="text" th:value="*{{date}}" required="required" />
<input id="time" name="time" type="text" th:value="*{{time}}" />
```

This works fine for displaying values, but when form is posted, both time and date values are null inside controller. Is there a way to make this work?

source code

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

import murderstats.web.domain.FormHDetails;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/formh")
public class FormHController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(@ModelAttribute("detailsItem") FormHDetails detailsItem) {
        detailsItem.setDate(new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime()));
        return "/formh/test";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test" , params={"save"})
    public String test_save(@ModelAttribute("detailsItem") FormHDetails detailsItem,
                                final BindingResult bindingResult) {        
        // detailsItem.date is null here
        return "redirect:/formh";
    }
}
```

```
import java.sql.Date;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

public class FormHDetails {

    @DateTimeFormat (pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date date;
}
```

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/formh/test}" method="post" th:object="${detailsItem}">
    <div>
        <label for="date">Date</label>
        <input id="date" name="date" type="text" th:field="*{date}" required="required" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="save">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: have you tried to use th:field in stead of th:value?

Comment: @Blejzer, yes, still nulls

Comment: Need more info. Can you please provide class, controller, and view?

Comment: @Blejzer even if I use input type 'date' that gives me a date picker I still see null value

Comment: @Blejzer added more source code

Comment: I'll provide you with changes in a moment. your controller seems to be the one creating all the problems...

Answer (score 1):

Few things...
Basically, your controller is not passing the object properly to the controller, and it is not receiving what he is expecting...:

```
// GET Method 
@RequestMapping(value={"/test"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getFormH(Model model){
FormHDetails detailsItem = new FormHDetails(); // or whatever constructor you use...

detailsItem.setDate(new DateTime().toDate); // import and use Joda Time is simpler...
    model.addAttribute("itemAttribute", detailsItem);

    return "/formh/test";
}
```

Next, you need to define POST method in your controller. You do so by changing method in request mapping to POST, and you need to tell controller that you are expecting form to provide information in form of your object FormHDetails:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/test"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public postFormH(@ModelAttribute("itemAttribute") FormHDetails detailsItem, final BindingResult bindingResult) {
// check if the form is properly sent?    
if(bindingResult.hasErrors(){
   return "formh/test";
}
// If everything went fine, print the date and redirect me
System.out.println(detailsItem.date);
return "redirect:/formh";
}
```

OK, so now you should have proper working controller that will process GET and POST request.

Now, in your view, just change the th:object to process what the controller is sending:

```
th:object="${itemAttribute}"
```

this should work...

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean here "your controller is not passing the object properly to the controller"

Comment: WOW, I managed to get myself all messed up here... Sorry for misleading you, the error is somewhere else obviously! Please disregard my post. Can you add @Valid in front of your @ModelAttribute and provide any errors that you get using `System.out.println(bindingResult.toString());`? It should provide some useful information.

Comment: I've already solved the problem and will post the answer a little later today. The controller was fine, but you give me and idea to use joda time, so I upvoted your answer.